# Any reason why an Android Class might be completely commented out?

Tags: android

I inherited some code where there are some Activity classes that are completely commented out. I'm having trouble figuring out where the activity code is actually happening and so I'm just wondering if `/*` at the beginning of a class might have some special significance to Android that I don't know about

Comment: No, comments in Android are the same as regular Java. Regarding your activities, you might want to have a look at the AndroidManifest.xml file since activities have to be registered there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it has no special meaning. The code is somewhere and it's not commented out.